# Netbeans 8.2 y Jboss 7.0

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, jboss

estoy intentando correr Jboss 7.0.0 en Netbeans 8.2 y no es posible.
Al momento de configurarlo el IDE me dice "JBoss 7 support needs at least JBoss 7.1.0"

Funciona correctamente con Jboss 7.1.1 o con cualquier Wildfly (8,9,10), pero para un proyecto especifico si o si necesito usar Jboss 7.0.0.

He probado con Eclipse y funciona correctamente con el 7.0.0, pero estoy mas familiarizado con Netbeans.

alguna idea?

Gracias!

Comment: ¿por qué no pruebas con una versión más antigua de NetBeans?

Comment: Probe con la 8.1 y tampoco funciona, quiza deba probar con la 8.0. gracias por el comentario

el 8.2 deberia soportarlo...
https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/relnotes.html

Comment: Esto parece un plugin para NetBeans y Jboss, igual te vale... https://github.com/okulikov/jboss-as7-netbeans

Comment: Gracias, voy a probar.

Comment: ¿haz intentado con Netbeans 11   https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb110/index.html?